# How to take photo shots in Sceneform?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, sceneform

I'm designing a Augmented Reality Android application using Sceneform. It should be able to take a photo shot with the virtual 3D objects and the physical environment, but the application keeps on crashing. I created a class `WritingArFragment` in Java and reference it in a fragment, but it's not working.

It says the Class `WritingArFragment` is never used.
For example, when I change `android:name="fully.qualified.class.name.WritingArFragment" to android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"`

it works, but when I leave it as `fully.qualified.class.name.WritingArFragment"`, it always crashes.

I want the application to take a photo of the AR environment together with 3D objects without crashing.

I was following the [Sceneform Tutorials from](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sceneform-intro/index.html?index=..%2F..io2018#14)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . 
Share relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is this. If you have created another application for this and created all the code content in that application then you need to add your file path instead of google's.

Remove this line from ArFragment from your xml file and add your file's path:

```
android:name="fully.qualified.class.name.WritingArFragment"
```

Example:

```
android:name="yourpackagename.WritingArFragment"
android:name="com.example.sceneform.WritingArFragment" // this is an example only
```

If you hit Ctrl + Space bar in windows then you may get the suggestion for that file.

I did that change and it worked for me. And follow the Codelabs tutorial for taking the photo. It is working I've tried it..

Answer (score 0):

From The Tutorial you attached .Its clearly mentioned that

> Create a new class called WritingArFragment **with a super class of**
>   com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment

It means either use google by default class `com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment` or **extends** your `WritingArFragment` with Google's `ArFragment` like this

```
public class WritingArFragment extends ArFragment
```